# What is advantage of using Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript

what is advantage of using Object.assign() compare with direct assign?

e.g>

```
Object.assign(obj, {a: true});
obj.a = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Which means you can assign multiple values at a time

> It is also super handy for copying whole objects. It's often used to merge "option" objects with some default values (similar to _.extend).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Also super handy for copying whole objects. It's often used to merge "option" objects with some default values (similar to _.extend)